# Nuxt3 try to read qrcode

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I expected this code to read QR codes, but nothing is displayed on the screen. I only see a warning that says "Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: undefined." The warning appears at  and <Qrbox onVnodeUnmounted=fn.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <ClientOnly>
        <qrcode-reader @decode="onDecode" @error="onError"></qrcode-reader>
      </ClientOnly>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { QrcodeReader } from "vue3-qrcode-reader";
  
  const onDecode = (content) => {
    console.log("Decoded QR code:", content);
  };
  
  const onError = (error) => {
    console.error("QR code scanning error:", error);
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: try latest version, looking at repo they removed the QrcodeReader component [see commit](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader/commit/3bbe9691b681298128b710648798d43e7cfa4495), seems you need use QrcodeStream instead, review the docs again https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader